# Scriptable objects are not saved when the project window is cycled

Tags: unity-game-engine, scriptable-object

When you eat an item, the item is added to the scriptable object. And when UNI.T turns off and on, the items you ate are saved well. However, if you cycle the project, it will not be saved.

I made scriptable object again and looked at scriptable object when it turned off, but it couldn't be saved

Comment: What do you mean by cycling the project window?

Comment: Scriptable objects are not saved when the project window is turned off and on again.

Comment: Why would you "turn off" project window?

Answer (score 0):

Clears and re-creates scriptable objects. If that doesn't work, check the function of eating again. Perhaps the code you add to the inventory when you eat the item is strange. If this bug does not resolve, please repost the question. I hope this bug will be resolved as the same developer.